# gnuplot - get errors on fit parameters, get fit output values as variables, print variable to screen

Tags: variables, gnuplot, curve-fitting, data-fitting, function-fitting

## Initial Question (Partially Answered)

I am using gnuplot's fitting routines to fit a function to some data, and extract a "characteristic decay time constant". (I call this parameter `d` in my fitting function.)

I have used the script code `set fit quiet` to prevent reams of text being printed to the terminal. However I now have no way of knowing what the final fit values were! (Except by inspecting the log file... which is arduous...)

Is there a way I can get the final fit parameter values back, store them in a variable, and print that variable?

I guess this is 2 questions in one... How do I print a variables value?

## Answer to Initial Question

So after some playing around with gnuplot, I have found that the `print` command can print variables to screen, and that the parameters, eg `d` are already available for use as variables - ie; they are *already* variables.

So I can do the following: `print "d=",d` - the comma here is used to separate things you want to print. So I first print a string `"d="` followed by the value of `d`.

## Next Question

How do I obtain the errors on the variables I have used? Eg; if I fit a function with parameters a,b and c, how can I print the errors on these values?

Comment: Quoting from the documentation: `If activated by using
"set fit errorvariables", the error for each fitted parameter will be stored in a variable named  like  the  parameter,  but  with "_err" appended.`

Comment: @Christoph Fantastic thanks - must have missed that when reading the docs earlier this week.

Comment: @Christoph Do you have a reference for this - it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: @Christoph My bad - spelling error - it works fine, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting the documentation:

> If activated by using `set fit errorvariables`, the error for each fitted parameter will be stored in a variable named like the parameter, but with "_err" appended.